# I can't find an old question of mine

Tags: support, questions

I asked a question on Math Stack Exchange about a month ago. It did not get any response. Now, I visited my profile in order to view the question. But it is not there. All the other questions I asked are visible there, but this question is not present. I searched a lot for it, but I can't find it.

I'm sure I never deleted it. How is it gone from my account?

Comment: This question pertains only to a specific site in the Stack Exchange Network. Questions on Meta Stack Exchange should pertain to our network or software that drives it as a whole, within the guidelines defined in the [help]. You should ask this question on the meta site where your concern originated. (Per our close reason)

Comment: [your deleted recent questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/309663)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question probably had a negative score, or closed, which makes it fit for [automatic deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

You should be able to find it in your [deleted recent questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/272963) page though. (Link for this page exists in the Questions tab of your profile page.)

Using Google Cache, I found your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558466/problem-about-periodicity-of-function

You posted it more than 60 days ago, hence it's not visible in the "deleted recent questions" page. (it's not recent.)

Comment: But the fact is that I can't view it in deleted recent questions.

Comment: Because you forgot you posted it much more than a month ago. Double than that.